# cpp/c++ compilation error: combaseapi.h - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, visual-studio-code, header-files

i have been working on a project that creates thread using CoInitializeEx function in cpp/c++.
When i try to compile the code, i get the following error;
"fatal error: combaseapi.h: No such file or directory\n compilation terminated."

I am on windows 10 and using VS code as IDE.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

This is what i tried:

1. googling for a while but couldn't find the solution.

I do have compaseapi header file under the following path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um

2. Tried re-installing windows SDK

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Don't tag both unless you're specifically asking about their differences.

Comment: Your VS Code is misconfigured.

Comment: What compiler? Looks like GCC, where did you install it from? It shouldn't need any external SDKs, this file should be bundled with the compiler (unsure if MinGW can work with MS SDKs directly).

Answer (score 0):

If you have this file on your file system, but you get this kind of error, then your project is misconfigured. Adding the path you are mentioning to your include paths should help.